# Symfony 3 - CollectionType of EntityType - Ajax submission (FOS REST)

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have form which is associating barcodes with assets.

There can be multiple barcodes associated with each asset.

The Entity entries for the Asset and Barcodes are:

**Asset Entity -> barcodes**

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection $barcodes
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Barcode", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"updated" = "DESC"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="asset_barcode",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="asset_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="barcode_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true, nullable=false)}
 *      )
 */
protected $barcodes;
```

**Barcode Entity -> barcode**

```
/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Asset", mappedBy="barcodes", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $barcode;
```

**AssetType** form

```
public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
{
    $builder
            ->add( 'id', HiddenType::class, ['label' => false] )
            ->add( 'serial_number', TextType::class, ['label' => false] )
            ->add( 'model', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'common.model'
            ] )
            ->add( 'location', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Location',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'asset.location',
                'choice_translation_domain' => false
            ] )
            ->add( 'barcodes', CollectionType::class, [
                'label' => 'asset.barcode',
                'entry_type' => BarcodeType::class,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'label' => false,
                'empty_data' => null,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'delete_empty' => true,
                'mapped' => false,
                'prototype_name' => '__barcode__'
            ] )
            ->add( 'comment', TextType::class, [
                'label' => false
            ] )
            ->add( 'active', CheckboxType::class, ['label' => 'common.active'] )
    ;
    $builder->get( 'model' )
            ->addModelTransformer( new ModelToIdTransformer( $this->em ) );
    $builder->get( 'barcodes' )
      ->addModelTransformer( new BarcodeToEntityTransformer( $this->em ) );
}
```

The BarcodeToEntityTransformer is receiving **null** data.  I determined this by using **dump** and **die**.

**BarcodeType** form

```
class BarcodeType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
    {
        $builder
                ->add( 'id', HiddenType::class, ['label' => false] )
                ->add( 'updated', HiddenType::class, ['label' => false, 'disabled' => true] )
                ->add( 'barcode', TextType::class, [
                ] )
                ->add( 'comment', TextType::class, [
                    'label' => false
                ] )
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions( OptionsResolver $resolver )
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults( array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Barcode'
        ) );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'barcode';
    }

}
```

**barcodes prototype**

```
<div id="asset_barcodes" data-prototype=" <div class="form-row barcode"><input type="hidden" id="asset_barcodes___barcode___updated" name="asset[barcodes][__barcode__][updated]" disabled="disabled" /><span class="input"><input type="text" id="asset_barcodes___barcode___barcode" name="asset[barcodes][__barcode__][barcode]" /></span><span class="comment"><input type="text" id="asset_barcodes___barcode___comment" name="asset[barcodes][__barcode__][comment]" /></span><span class="remove-form-row" title="Remove" id="barcode-__barcode__"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></span></div> "></div>
```

My problem is that the barcode data does not seem to be seen when submitted with **application/json**.

[image: JSON data]

There is a little extra data being sent as a side effect of the page architecture.

How should the barcodes data be submitted in order to be read properly by the form?  Or, what changes do I need to make to the form?

Comment: Why do you have `'mapped' => false` in your `AssetType` form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, apparently, with  `'mapped' => false,`

This option is used for the fields of the form, which are unrelated to a model (f.e. for a "accept rules" checkboxes or stuff like this)

Symfony in this case does not process data from this field in any way and does not set it to model.